# Auto-suggestion HTML and CSS code without an extension in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, autosuggest

I just installed Visual Studio Code. It works and suggests HTML and stylesheet and JavaScript as well, but what matters is that I didn't install any extension in Visual Studio Code, and it works well without HTML and JavaScript extension.

How does it work without any extension? Do I need to install an extension for this?

Comment: I suppose it's Emmet you are seeing, which is installed by default. I would suggest installing live server extension too for easy coding.

Answer (score 1):

To answer it on Low-Level, VS Code is built on top of `monaco-editor`

As mentioned in its docs, it has below stuffs by default

> Rich IntelliSense, Validation TypeScript, JavaScript, CSS, LESS, SCSS,
> JSON, HTML

Refer: https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/

Those shortcut features are built with https://emmet.io/

So, for working with basic web stuffs, you don't need an extension.